# how to install sass on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd, sass

I cannot install Sass to my machine although I had downloaded ruby and printed on cmd :

```
cd C:/ruby22
```

then:

```
gem install sass
```

but I get as result:

```
'gem' is not recognized as an internal command, operable program or batch file
```

how to install it please?

Comment: Get the Ruby executables on your path first?

Comment: Try going to your Start menu and look for "Start Command Prompt with Ruby", I find Ruby commands generally work in there.

Comment: Are you sure that none of those related questions listed over there on the side don't answer your question? `------->`

Answer (score 3):

You can install Sass on Windows by downloading the package for your operating system from GitHub  select [latest release](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/) 
extract the downloaded zip file

Now note download the extracted zip file path. For example D:\MyUserName\dart-sass

- Set system environment variable. Step depends which version of
  Windows you're using:
- If you're using Windows 8 or 10, press the Windows key, then search 
      for and select "System (Control Panel)".
- If you're using Windows 7, right click the "Computer" icon on the
  desktop and click "Properties". Click "Advanced system settings".
  Click "Environment Variables".
- Under "System Variables", find the PATH variable, select it, and
  click "Edit". If there is no PATH variable, click "New".
- Add your directory to the beginning of the variable value followed
  by ; (a semicolon). For example, if the value was
  C:\Windows\System32, change it to
  C:\Users\Me\bin;C:\Windows\System32.
- Click "OK".

That's all—there are no external dependencies and nothing else you need to install.

- now open command prompt
- run `sass --version`
- to be sure it installed correctly.

When you install Sass on the command line, you'll be able to run the sass executable to compile .sass and .scss files to .css files. For example:

```
sass --watch input.scss output.css
```

Once it's all set up, [Sass Basics](https://sass-lang.com/guide).

---

*how i am converting .scss to .css*

i have created a windows batch file in my project/content/scss folder(where all my scss files are) with below commands.

1. `cd..` (When you need to go one folder up, use the "cd.." command.)
2. `sass --watch scss\:scss\` (You can also watch individual files or
   directories with the `--watch` flag.)

saved it as

> watch scss.bat

now whenever i am working on my sass file i run the "watch scss.bat"

the above command execute and watch my all my .scss files and update .css file for the same:)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install ruby, see: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki
2. Open a command prompt, click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK.
3. Run `gem install sass`

Possible related to your issue: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

**This is for Windows**

1. First step is to [download ruby](https://rubyinstaller.org), install it, then add it to your executable path.
2. Now go to your folder where ruby was installed and check if it was installed with `ruby -v` command.
3. Then, open the folder where you have installed ruby and install sass using `gem install sass`.
4. That's it!! You are good to go!! If you still have doubts, run `sass -v` and it will give you a version.

**For Mac**

Just run `gem install sass` as ruby is preinstalled on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: https://rubyinstaller.org/ using CMD [gem install sass]

Step 2: http://compass-style.org/install/ using CMD

[gem update --system] [gem install compass]

for more details https://github.com/iz-syed/base_path/blob/master/README.md